Why assignment operator and its 'variants' doesnt show up in the 'Precedence table' of python?
I was searching in the python documentation in order to get the 'Precedence table' of the operators in python, here it is (at least for python 3.12.7), Section 6.17:
https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence
The final column says 'assignment expression', and shows the operator:
:=
Im learning python and i dont know this operator yet, but i expected to see in this column (or at least in the table) the operators like:
=, +=, -=, *=, /=, ...
Where are they? or how can i know whats the precedence of this operators? Why they are not present in the 'Precedence table'?
Thanks for your time

Those augmented assignments are not expressions. It doesn't make sense to mention the order of operation in this case since a = or *= can't appear in an expression. := is mentioned because it's an expression, so it can appear within other expressions.
With an assignment statement, the entire right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.

Because Assignment works differently in Python than in C. In C, assignment is evaluated (often the result is discarded), so it has a precedence with all the other evaluations.
In python, += is an "augmented assignment". It does +1, and it evaluates the LH before doing the addition.  But the assignment itself isn't a result, the statement can't be evaluated, so it doesn't have a place in the order of evaluations.

Thanks for your answer!, so unlike C, where assignment is an expression (and due to that it can be evaluated and returns a value) python assignments are not expressions and doesnt return a value right?
I guess this is the reason why in the REPL/Python shell an assignment doesnt eturn anything, thanks man!
